# name 'IntegrityError' is not defined - why can't I used 'except: IntegrityError' on this script?

Tags: python, django, exception, model

I'm running a script from inside a django application at the very root of the app_name folder; as in app_name>app_name.

At the top of the script I have this:

```
import os
import sys
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE','versal.settings')
import django
django.setup()
```

I'm trying to handle an integrity error - my slugs need to be unique, so when one isn't unique, I want to handle the integrity error by adding a '1' to the slug.

```
        try:
            podcast_instance.slug = slugify(parsed_podcast.title)
            podcast_instance.save()
            podcast_saves += 1
        except IntegrityError:
            podcast_instance.slug = slugify(parsed_podcast.title + '1')
            podcast_instance.save()
            podcast_saves += 1
```

When I run this code, I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "podcasts.py", line 166, in <module>
    podcasty()
  File "podcasts.py", line 159, in podcasty
    submit(podcast_objects,podcast_rss)
  File "podcasts.py", line 73, in submit
    except IntegrityError as e:
NameError: name 'IntegrityError' is not defined
```

Answer (score 30):

You need to import it before using it.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError
```